# Pervasive DLL initialization failure on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, 32bit-64bit

I'm currently in the process of migrating some web applications from a 32-bit Windows Server 2K3 box to a new 64-Bit Windows 2008R2 box.

The applications themselves seem to run fine (they use Classic ASP and some 32-bit libraries for Classic ASP and all is well there) but when they try to make a connection to Pervasive 8.5 (the version we need to use) I'm presented with the following ODBC error:

> Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 1114: A
>   dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Pervasive
>   ODBC Client Interface, C:\PVSW\Bin\w3odbcci.dll).

I have tried to re-install the application but to no avail and the driver doesn't show up in the 32-bit ODBC Data Sources on the server either.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [KB 00018076](http://www.pervasivedb.com/kb/Pages/00018076.aspx) in the knowledgebase for Pervasive PSQL, you need to upgrade to v10.30 or newer to get support for Windows Server 2008 R2.

And I found another article, [KB 00016992](http://www.pervasivedb.com/kb/Pages/00016992.aspx) which indicates that support for 64-bit operating systems was added in v9.5.

It sounds like you're stuck using Windows Server 2003.